# jQuery UI sortable - do something when item is dragged

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two block one is "draggable" and the other is "sortable".

What I want to do is when I start dragging  an item  from "sortable" to do something via jQuery.

Here's my JS:

```
 $(".sortableList").sortable({

 });
 $(".draggable").draggable({
  connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  helper: 'clone',
  revert: 'invalid',
  start: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).addClass('testing');
 }
 });
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yivazadebate/1/edit)

Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add update event at sortable like this :

```
     $(".sortableList").sortable({ 
            update: function(event, ui) {
               //alert("Do something here when item left!");
            },
            start: function(event, ui) {
               //alert("Do something here when item just dragged from sortable!");
        },
     });
```

So when the dragged from sortable is left to the position `update` event will trigger and when it dragged `.start` is triggered.

Comment: This is not what I'm expecting. I'm expecting to do something when I start dragging the the item from "sortableList", not after I'm dropping it.

Comment: My bad, I wasn't specific enough in my question that I want to do something when I start dragging the item.

Comment: I updated the answer , you have to use .start .Try it