# jQuery UI sortable - do something when user starts dragging an element from a specific block

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192255/jquery-ui-sortable-do-something-when-item-is-dragged)

I have two block one is "draggable" and the other is "sortable".

What I want to do is when I start dragging an item from "sortable" to do something via jQuery.

this is my JS:

```
 $(".sortableList").sortable({
 start: function(event, ui) {
       alert("Do something here!");
    }
 });
 $(".draggable").draggable({
 connectToSortable: '.sortableList',
 cursor: 'pointer',
 helper: 'clone',
 revert: 'invalid',
 start: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).addClass('testing');
 }
 });

 $("#sidebar-wrapper").droppable({
 accept: 'li',
 drop: function (event, ui) {
     ui.helper.remove();
 }
 });
```

The problem is that is doing something before I drop the element from "draggable" to "sortableList" and I want to do something when element is dragged from "sortableList."

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yivazadebate/3/edit).

Any suggestions on how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would count as a bug in the jQuery UI Sortable or not - it certainly seems that it might be.  One way you can get around it is to query the `event` parameter in `start`:

```
$(".sortableList").sortable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
        if (event.handleObj.namespace=="sortable")
            alert("Do something here!");
    }
});
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/layifamolafe/1/edit)

Comment: @agis In what way?  I only see the alert when I specifically start dragging one of the items within the sortable now.  Make sure that you've hit the "Run with JS" button on JSBin if it's turned off Auto Run